# How to Keep the elements on ends in Row() widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using below `Row` widget in flutter , which is nested in a `Column` widget and on screen it appears shared in the screenshot

[image]

I want to the Row elements to appear at extreme ends with some padding. How can I do that?

```
 Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(width:20,),

                    Text("Mark ALL READ"),

                    SizedBox(width:200,),
                    Text("Clear All"),

                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the row to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` should place the elements on both ends of the row.

To add some padding you should be able to just place the whole `Row()` widget into a `Padding()` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Okk this one you can do with below code. You need to wrap Row in Padding and use mainAxisALignment on Row.

```
 Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Text("Mark ALL READ"),
        SizedBox(
          width: 200,
        ),
        Text("Clear All"),
      ],
    ),
   ),
```